# React Native How to create a createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

```
export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Auth: AppNavigator,
    Main: MainTabNavigator, // Tab Menu After login
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
 )
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
   Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
  }
);
```

I want to create a createStackNavigator outside the MainTabsNavigator because I want to create the back and forward animation, so I want to put all the Screen outside the MainTabScreen inside a createStackNavigator. Now I don't see to get it right. I'm getting this error:

```
The component for route 'Auth' must be a React component.
```

Comment: This will happen when the imported Component has not been properly exported.

Comment: what are your AppNavigator components, question is a bit unclear

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `createStackNavigator` into `createAppContainer` :

```js
export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Auth: AppNavigator,
    Main: MainTabNavigator, // Tab Menu After login
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
 )
);

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator(
  {
   Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
  }
));
```

Comment: You shouldn't create 2 app containers like this. This will also give an error because you use `AppNavigator` before defining it below.

Comment: Your right i move my add AppNavigator to a higher level and it work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solve if I move the AppNavigator up.

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
  Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
 }
);


export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
{
AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
Auth: AppNavigator,
Main: MainTabNavigator, // Tab Menu After login
},
 {
initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
}
)
```

);